# How do I manage static assets with backpack

Tags: node.js, webpack

I use [backpack](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/backpack#customizing-webpack-config) with express server.I found some backend codes have fs.readFile(path) and these files located in src/assets/* which is not included build path.For example I use sequelize and need to read some files.

```
fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });
```

I want to know how these files should be managed because they throw file missing errors. I have some ideas 
are followed by

1. Use FileLoader or URL-Loader or another configuration set webpack
2. Locate assets in build directory in advance.
3. user import jsfiles instead of fs.readFile
4. Stop using backpack.

I need to read js files dynamically, so first solution needs a bit irritating extension modification.
Second we may no longer need backpack, so we had better choice 4th.
Third are reasonable but, some codes needs to rewrite and, if many files are such that, it's not easy to check them.

Do you have better solutions of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved that using require.context which handle dynamic require modules during compile processes.

```
 var context   = require.context(__dirname ,false,/\.\/(?!index).*\.js$/)  
 context.keys().forEach(
  (file) => {
    if (!sequelize.importCache[file]) {
      let modelDefine = context(file)
      if (typeof modelDefine === 'object') {
        // ES6 module compatibility
        modelDefine = modelDefine.default
      }
      var model = modelDefine(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes)
      sequelize.importCache[file] = model
      db[model.name] = model
    }
  }
)
```

this is no needs locating assets because these modules bundle built files.

see [enter link description here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html)